# Simple distance question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a car travels m kilometres in h hours, how much time will it take to travel M kilometres?

(A) M/m hours

(B) mh/M hours

(C) M/h hours

(D) Mh/m hours

(E) Mm/h hours

I honestly do not understand what the question is asking.

I think the formula is m.h = H.M so (m.h)/M is the time it takes.

But the answer is D.

Comment: First step: If it takes $h$ hours to travel $m$ kilometers, how many hours will it take to travel one km? Second step: now if you know how many hours for one km, how many hours for $M$ km?

Comment: Speed $\times$ Time = Distance.  Rearrange this to get Time = Distance / Speed.  Plugging in our variables, that is $M / (m/h)$ or simplifying, $Mh/m$

Answer (score 1):

Let's swap the letters for round numbers e.g. if it first travels 10km (for $m$) in say 3 hours, how long would it take to travel 20km (for $M$).

$\frac{20}{10} = 2$ i.e. it has to travel twice as far, so it would take twice as long $2h$, at the same speed, i.e. 6 hours.

Now we put the letters in

$\frac{M}{m}\times h$

it's the same as $D$